# SwiftUI TextEditor disable return key

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, textfield, text-editor

I was wondering how I can disable the "return" key in the keyboard for TextEditor in SwiftUI?

I need a TextField that supports multiple lines (around 140 characters) so I found that I can use TextEditor. The problem is that I can't find out how to change the "return" key on the board to "Done" or simply disable it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's some code:

```
@State var annotationText = "Say something..."
//
TextEditor(text: $annotationText)
    .onReceive(annotationText.publisher.collect()) {
      annotationText = String($0.prefix(140))
  }
 .onTapGesture {
     if annotationText == "Say something..." {
         annotationText = ""
     }
 }
.frame(height: 50)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need to add a condition that will enable/disable the return key on run time and change it to `Done`? Or do you just need to simply disable it or change to `Done`?

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution by manually getting/setting the binding variable:

```
TextEditor(text: Binding(
    get: {
        return annotationText
    },
    set: { value in
        var newValue = value
        if value.contains("\n") {
            newValue = value.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
        }
        annotationText = newValue
    }
))
```